# How to exchange 100 EUR for INR?

Tags: india, foreign-exchange

My uncle gave me a 100 euro note as a gift. How can I get it cashed in rupees?

I don't have a passport. Please tell me where I can convert it and what documents are required.

Comment: By Rupees you mean Indian Rupees? And are you located in India?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to walk over to any Bank that deals with Foreign Exchange or go to any Western union Money Transfer agencies, they will take the Euro and give you Indian Rupees. Passport is not required, but a proof of identity is required. Banks will also ask you question as to how you got the money, as long as you are able to answer them you will get the money.

There would also be local Jewellary stores that would convert the money. If you are dealing with them be sure you have check the rates with few before going into the deal.

Answer (score 1):

You take it to a bank or Foregn Exchange agent and exchange it for your rupees (I assume this is your national currency). They will exchange it at the current exchange rate and some may charge you fee for doing it.

Answer (score -2):

You can convert your money at a money transfer office at an airport.

Comment: Welcome to PF&M! I edited your answer to make it a bit easier to read. It might also be more helpful if you could expand it to explain the advantages and disadvantages of this approach compared to the other answers and any pitfalls to watch out for (such as typical exchange rates).